# How angularJS ngResource pass variables to expressJS when doing http request operations to server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angularjs-resource

The issue here is, that i don't know how to pass some scope.data to expressjs when using ngResource, so then it can be used with express route to insert something to DB.

ExpressJS REST

```
 router.route('/Data')
    .get(function(req,res){
     var username = req.username;
     var collection = db.collection('users');
   collection.find({username:username}).toArray(function (err, doc){
       res.send(doc[0].pets);
   });
 })
   .post(function(req,res){

  !!//I would like to use some data from angular here//!!
    var name = req.body.name;
    var surname = req.bodysurname;

    collection.update({username: username}, {
        $push: {
            "details": {
                name: name,
                surname: surname
             }
         }
     }, function (err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;          
      });
    });
```

Angular Factory

```
 (function() {
   'use strict';

 angular
     .module('App')
     .factory('Factory', function ($resource) {
         return $resource("/Data",{},
             { get:{ method:"GET",
                     cache:true,
                     isArray:true},
              save:{ method:"POST",
                     cache:true,
                     isArray:false
               }});
        });
    })();
```

Controller.js

This one works fine i use this function with ng-click()

```
$scope.load = function(){
        Factory.get(function (data){
           $scope.data = data;
        });
    };
```

With this one i have problem i have ng-models name and surname in view and i would like to send them to server so it can be used in REST route as req.body.name and req.body.surname.

```
 $scope.AddData = function(){
        Factory.save()
        }); 
      };
```

I think that data should be passed here in this function AddData, however i haven't succeeded yet.

So i tried as Jesus said but without results?

```
 $scope.AddData = function(){
       Factory.save($scope.name) //I tried ({name:$scope.name}) too
     }); 
    };
```

After advices from Jesús Quintana I checked the details of method POST and it occurred that everything was all right on angular side i was missing extension of body parser on server Express side

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

So now it looks like this

```
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgResource works like a class with private and public methods:

For example Factory.save() is a public method and you must pass the data to be stored in the server, for example:

```
$scope.AddData = function(factoryData){
    Factory.save(factoryData);
    }); 
  };
```

But also have a private method and the above example is the same to this:

```
$scope.AddData = function(factoryData){
    var factory = new Factory(factoryData); 
    factory.$save(); // Is the same method but is private because factory is a instance of the factory
    }); 
  };
```

Both example are valid methods but must be used of differents ways.

**EDIT**

I create this little plunkr to see the network request: http://plnkr.co/edit/1bdblyrsW0jr7rXIAVNn?p=

[image]

Comment: I updated my question accordingly to your advices but without success, can you show me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: mmm the second must work (with the object {name: value}), Tested in a plunkr and the request contain the payload. For you server syntax suppose you are using expressjs, check if you have this in your code app.use(express.bodyParser());

Comment: Edit the answer to paste the plunkr and the network request from that example.